# Bulk insertion with input from mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I am playing around with mongodb bulk operations.

I found this useful link and succeeded in bulk insertions

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.insert/#Bulk.insert

But in `bulk.insert` what if i want to get the value of `item` from the mongodb and give it as input to the bulk operation

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.insert( { item: "abc123", defaultQty: 100, status: "A", points: 100 } );
bulk.insert( { item: "ijk123", defaultQty: 200, status: "A", points: 200 } );
bulk.insert( { item: "mop123", defaultQty: 0, status: "P", points: 0 } );
bulk.execute();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the item values you inserted, try using Bulk.getOperations(). It returns an array of write operations executed through Bulk.execute().

[Bulk.getOperations()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.getOperations/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not interested in operations performed. let's say i want to insert a collection and the value of defaultQty should come from mongodb.